# In Chrome, my text is hidden behind my background image

Tags: html, css, image, google-chrome, background-image

http://codepopper.com/leon/health/

Hello! Hoping for some help on this... If you view the link above in FireFox you will be able to see the text in each of the green rows. However in Chrome for some reason the text is hidden behind, I've played with the Z-index, but is there something else I'm missing?

HTML:

```
<!-- Video Row 1 -->
<div class="row">
    <img src="images/thumb1.png" alt="Top five tips, facts, myths, and heartburn treatments."/>
    <div class="copyBox">
        Top five tips, facts, myths, and heartburn treatments.
            <img class="float_right" src="images/play_button.png" />
    </div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.row {
    float:left;
    width:300px;
    height: 60px;
    background: url(../images/tile_row.jpg) repeat-x;
    clear: none;
    z-index: -1;
}

.copyBox {
    float:right;
    text-align: left;
    width: 192px;
    height: 60px;
    font-family: arial;
    font-size: 12;
    left: 5px;
    top: 5px;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll need to decrease the width on .copyBox to ~190px. The text is getting pushed out of the container. Also, you can remove the z-index since it only works on positioned elements and you should specify units for your font-size :)

Comment: Oh wow thanks! That fixed it :D can't believe Chrome was that picky over 2 pixels. Another quick Q, how would I align the Play Button to the bottom right hand corner?

Comment: I'd add and modify the following rules:

`.copyBox { position:relative; }
img.float_right { position:absolute; top:28px; left:100px; }`

Setting the relative position for .copybox makes everything inside able to be positioned just how you want it.